# 2012 way of python based web-application-development

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, web2py, tornado

I need some advice. I am thinking of learning web-development.

To start with I have kept the requirements

- I am looking for a nice/easy/fast/simple python based web-application-stack.
- The purpose is to learn and build a commercial scalable application.
- Which teaches me un-ambigous best-practiced development, majorly web-development.
- My development-environment-of-choice ubuntu (altough i would like the project to cross-platform).
- My choice of development language python.
- To start with I would like to develop a delicious-social-tagging kind of application.
- It will be great, after i develop my application, give it to my friend as a zip. He unzips and just run it. Something like xampp setup.

As of now i am finding web2py better than all. But can i use tornado web server with it. Is it possible to run tornado as only event-based web-server, and not use its FrameWork part?

What have I looked at ?
- Django: Its like start menu for python-based-web-development. Does everybody starts from here?
- pylons/pyramid: they say lot of things, which I have no clue about.
- web2py: sounds most interesting as of now. It says it has best of everything else. Are they true with this claim?
- flask (pocoo.org): werkzeug is popular, and flask is by same guys. It may be another main-stream capable product?

Which DB ?
- MySQL
- PostGress
- SQLite

which server ?
- Apache ( i guess with mod_wsgi)
- ngix
- tornado
- cherrypy

How much shall following comparisons matter ?
- mod_python vs mod_wsi vs werkzeug (pocoo.org)
- Twisted vs thrift vs spdy
- torando vs ngix+mod_wsgi vs apachi_mod_wsgi vs tornado

Comment: If you are totally new to web development, I strongly suggest starting with Django.  The reference documentation is awesome and [the django book](http://www.djangobook.com/) covers enough grounds to help out people with little or no web development experience.  There are many reasons to choose Django over other frameworks, but IMHO excellent documentation and ease-of-access are by far Django's strongest points.

Comment: Vivek, there is no one way of development.

The devil is in the details of the requirement.
Choices are also based on competency.
For example, Flask/Bottle are mini web frameworks where your starting effort threshold is small but if you were to build large complex web application, you would end up re-inventing the wheels which are already provided by Django/Pylons etc. These frameworks are built to cater to different requirements and not necessarily because one is better than the other. If you want to knock-up a REST service quickly then flask/bottle helps.

See: SQLite vs MySQL

Comment: This question is almost impossible to answer in its current form.  There are not "fast/simple/easy" setups for "scalable commercial applications".  Also, best practices are often conflicting! You almost certainly have to do some kind of tradeoffs, which means there are no unambiguous sets of best practices.  Cross-platform application is possible, but cross-platform stack is a totally different game.  Finally software development is hard.  No one develops high-performance, high-quality applications on their first try.  Take time to learn each part of your stack.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed. The solution could have been a good post helping new developers understand the current state of the _incredibly_ fragmented python web world. $0.02

Comment: @Bashwork: indeed, but this questions adresses so many different topics that a single complete answer will likely be the size of a book.

Comment: i disagree. it's fragmented because there is no wrong choice. and ultimately the "solution" chosen would be the one that endorses the most popular framework(django) along with a long train of comments each mentioning all the others frameworks. There's plenty of information out there already. The OP just needs to choose one and slog through it.

Comment: @AndréCaron True, but a quick summary could have been useful. And TomWillis, I disagree with your disagreement. Your answer basically amounts to "go google it" which I feel (regardless of the question) is a lame response from a question site.

Comment: part-a
- comparing any two or few products will be always be "solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". If that was not the case and we always had a clear set/suite of technologies/product winner, then I am sure there would never be so many alternatives and also we would have a perfunctory open-source community. 
I asked this question to experienced and curious people to share their insights/experiements/finding with different suites. I find the reason for close bogus. 

I would like to re-open it, but i think i cant.

Comment: If you read the question deeply enough, a lot of googling have been done, otherwise how would a newbie know about all these options (relatively new options). I have read lot of things about product-a vs product-b... but i am not experienced/read enough to have know product-a when used with product-123 performs better than product-f with products-009. For ex web2py (according to me as it shall be fastest/cleanest to learn) when used over tornado (event-based efficent server) and using mySQL (easy/fast development, Facebook endorsed), would it leave everyone in dust for almost 90% of usecases.